# Should words in email subjects be capitalized?

Tags: capitalization, email

How should email subject lines be written? Like this:

> Question Regarding Tomorrow's Meeting

or like this:

> Question regarding tomorrow's meeting

For some reason, I would consider the latter to be less "professional." However, capitalizing each word as in a title may be a bit tedious, and it may even look awkward if someone has many emails with capitalized titles. Furthermore, [this website](http://corp.inntopia.com/capitalize-first-letter-of-every-word/) seems to suggest that the people are less likely to click on an email if each word is capitalized (though I'd probably take that with a grain of salt).

Comment: I'm just asking a general. My example was merely for illustration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no universal rules for capitalization in e-mail subject lines; the medium is too new and handles too many different types of communication to have developed a single convention. Adhere to the standards of your organization, the guidance of your editor, or the strictures of your preferred [style manual](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2579/16052).

Broadly speaking, sentence case is easier to read, and is the style I would expect for person-to-person communications. Title case is less personal, and might be appropriate where the subject represents a news headline or newsletter title, or by analogy to the title of a memo. I exclusively use sentence case for the e-mails I pen myself, but that is simply personal preference and opinion.